# Can restore background of Xorg to gray mesh?

Tags: background, x11, xorg

Can I restore a background of Xorg to the gray mesh of the old X11 as below screenshots?

http://dsl.org/cookbook/x-fvwm2.jpg

http://toastytech.com/guis/nbsd5icons.png

I'm trying in Xorg of Linux-based system distributed by Debian (stable version "stretch"). I tried `xsetroot -def` but my background was restored to black. I start X for test by `startx` from console with a `~/.xinitrc` file having one line `xterm`.

Comment: `xsetroot -bitmap <filename>`

Comment: thanks! I could get "gray mesh" background by `xsetroot -bitmap root_weave`. I got the "root_weave" file from [debian old archive](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian-2.2/main/source/x11/xfree86-1_3.3.6.orig.tar.gz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this question by `xsetroot -bitmap root_weave`